# Eslint rule to detect initialized class properties

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

Using `useDefineForClassFields:true` the following code is not valid anymore when targeting `es2022` : `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'array')`

```
class Bar {
    array = new Array();
}

class Foo {
    foo = this.bar.array; // Property 'bar' is used before its initialization

    constructor(private bar: Bar) {}
}

console.log(new Foo(new Bar()))
```

Is there an ESLint rule to trigger an error on this ?

PS: The target `EsNext` is triggering an error, but this is not what i'm looking for.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCYCdoG8CwAoaXqIWAntALzQB2ApgO7QCCCe+AFAJQDcGAvhhqJDAGIB7QSgzZoAM2HFoAFwAWASwgA6AEaIVuAq2gB6PdAAKCQQAdyCWYQDkGhDejLoAVwjkAJtDXkpCck6yMIqkirKKYCCKAF5g4YKk3JjYwAkQsgguwLKCCIxmCIoAbnEB9gBccIjMKFzodTxpgiDkKiCCAOaMFNRCgt1UVXnMI0A)

Comment: *ESLint* rule? I think the compiler should handle this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CaTS suggest, this should be a tsc error.

[There is an open bug about this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50971).